# passing a row of php data to an AngularJS modal

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a project that uses PHP and AngularJS together to save and display data. However, it's become a little out of hand for my beginner skills to understand how to bind to the data I'm displaying. What I need to do is to pass a "row" of php data to a modal that opens on ng-click. I've encoded a php into a json priorly in this project to pass the values for the login. Would I need to do a similar thing for this?

Here's the PHP page markup:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {

    echo '<tr ng-click="open()">';
    echo '<td class="wa-num">' . $row['wa_num'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td id="submitted-file">' . $row['file'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['rating'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['submit date'] . '</td></tr>';
}
```

And here's the modal markup:

```
<div>{{entry}}</div>
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
```

Here's the controller for "dashboard", for the php snippet above ^:

```
.controller('dashboard',['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$modal', 'loginService', function($scope, $rootScope, $location, $modal, loginService){

          var allowed = loginService.authenticate();

          allowed.get(
              function(result){
                  console.log(result);
                  if (result.loggedin !== undefined && result.loggedin === true) {
                      console.log("Welcome!");
                  }
              },
              function(result) {
                  $location.path("admin");
                  $rootScope.errorVisible = true;
              }
          );

          $scope.open = function () {

              var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                  templateUrl: '/partials/submission_mod.html',
                  controller: ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function($scope, $modalInstance){
                      $scope.modalInstance = $modalInstance;
                      $scope.entry = "Submission info goes here.";
                  }]
              });
          };

    }])
```

How would I pass php values to the "enrty" var? Tutorial links are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are confused. You should be creating an entry instance variable inside your controller, get values from the backend and initialize it to the entry instance variable. Then make sure your div is inside the scope of the controller i.e attach the controller to your div. Does it make sense to you? Or do you need more help?